# Combining url_helpers for a Rails engine and a base application in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-engines

I have a Rails 3.2.15 application with an Engine mounted as follows at the top of `routes.rb`:

```
mount Service::Engine => '/'
```

While testing my application I'd like to use the routes url_helpers for my engine and if the route does not exist, fall back to the main application.

For example, I have this route in the main app (`rake routes` output), which does NOT exist in the engine:

```
manager_account  GET  /manager/accounts/:id(.:format)     manager_accounts#show
```

I'm including url_helpers for both the application and the engine in `spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Service::Engine.routes.url_helpers, type: :feature
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers, type: :feature
end
```

My problem is that when I try to call `manager_account_path(account)` in my spec, I get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"manager_accounts", :id=>...
```

If I call it as `main_app.manager_account_path(account)` then it succeeds but I'd really like to avoid having to specify that every time. Is there any way to set this up where I can use my url_helpers such that if a route doesn't exist in the engine, it'll fall back to the base application?

Comment: Check this out if it can help you (sorry I have no reputation to comment on your post). http://pivotallabs.com/writing-rails-engine-rspec-controller-tests/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to test your engine code in the main app. I would recommend using the dummy application provided by the engine to test your engine code.

According to the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#testing-an-engine):

> When an engine is generated, there is a smaller dummy application created inside it at test/dummy. This application is used as a mounting point for the engine, to make testing the engine extremely simple. You may extend this application by generating controllers, models or views from within the directory, and then use those to test your engine.
>
> The test directory should be treated like a typical Rails testing environment, allowing for unit, functional and integration tests.